# Get day difference between 2 strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, difference

i'm getting 2 strings from php and i'm trying to get the difference between then using javascript. this is my code:

`this.now =  Thu Feb 14 2017 16:38:42 GMT-0200 (BRST) 
this.expiration  = Wed Feb 15 2017 15:29:45 GMT-0200 (BRST)`

and i want the days difference between this two dates, to show something like `"1"  day left`.

Comment: What Is The Date Format You Are Getting In?

Comment: not exactly duplication

Comment: @havenchyk, thank you. Im getting 2 strings in date format from an external api. and i don't know how split this strings, get the day on both and compare the result to show the days left...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

1) It's possible to use library like [[date-fns#differenceInDays](https://date-fns.org/docs/differenceInDays)]

2) Write your simple diff function

```
const msInDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000

function diffInDays(startDateString, endDateString) {
  const start = new Date(startDateString)
  const end = new Date(endDateString)

  const ms = end - start
  const fullDays = Math.round(ms / msInDay)

  return fullDays
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor is not recommended as it's almost entirely implementation dependent. There are [*many good answers*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript) to this question already.

Comment: @Rob well, a lot of answers contains even moment, not only Date constructor. Could you please point to *good answer*? Should I update answer with Date.parse?

Comment: The first answer is fine. Avoid any solution that uses the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) to parse a string.

Comment: @RobG but the first answer uses `new Date` :)

Comment: Yes, because that's the only way to create a Date instance. But it doesn't use Date to parse a string, it has its own *parseDate* function.